# How do I get the index number of currently displayed slide of a Views Slideshow into the jQuery Cycle's "Before" advanced option?

Tags: views

According to this [StackExchange Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276577/jquery-cycle-plugin-how-to-return-the-index-number-of-the-currently-displayed-s), you can access jQuery Cycle options like so:

```
//on before function
before: function (curr, next, opts) {
    alert(opts.nextSlide + " of " + opts.slideCount);
}
```

However, the instructions in the views plugin say, "If one of the options you add uses a function, example fxFn, then you need to only enter what goes inside the function call" so in the Advanced Options *before* box I only put:

```
alert(opts.nextSlide + " of " + opts.slideCount);
```

This code yields the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: opts is not defined` in the console.

How do I access these jQuery Cycle variables (mainly the index of the current slide) from within my "Before" advanced option code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JS code for views_slideshow_cycle:

```
case "before":
  var beforeValue = advancedOptions[option];

  beforeValue = Drupal.viewsSlideshowCycle.advancedOptionCleanup(beforeValue);
// transition callback (scope set to element to be shown):         
function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag)
  settings.opts[option] = function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
    pager_before_fn(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options);
      eval(beforeValue);
  }
  break;
```

Your code isn't actually executed within the scope of the `before` callback, it's executed afterwards. The variable that the module provides is named `options` rather than `opts`, hopefully that will resolve to what you need and the change should be as simple as:

```
alert(options.nextSlide + " of " + options.slideCount);
```